# Existence of Moments for Linear Regression With Pareto Error

Tags: regression, convergence, moments, pareto-distribution

Suppose I have the following model linear regression model:

$y = \beta_0 + x_1i\beta_1 + x_2i\beta_2 + e_i$ with $e_i \sim Pareto(k,\alpha)$

Now if $1< \alpha < 2$, I would suppose that the second moment of my parameters $\beta_i$ does not exist? With every observation I add the moment would jump around and never settle down.

Is this intuition and the ensuing conclusion valid?

I have been conducting some experiments where

$x_i \sim MVN(\mu, \Omega)$ with $\mu = [0.3, 1]$ and $\Omega = \left[ \begin{matrix}  5 & 3 \\ 3 & 2  \end{matrix}\right]$ and $\alpha = 1.5$

The setup is the following: I draw 1000 observations fit the described model and store the the coefficients and their standard deviation. I do this 10,000 times and calculate the cumulative mean of both the coefficients and the standard deviation, the results of which you find below (never mind the name tags, it's just $\beta_0 - \beta_2$). Somehow the standard deviation seems to converge to 0.6. This is somewhat puzzling to me. Am I going about this the wrong way and should instead calculate the cumulative variance of the coefficients?

[image: Convergence of the mean of the standard deviation]